# Shiny for Python: Implementing an asynchronous iterator (almost there)

Tags: python-asyncio, py-shiny

The endgame is making an app reactive to a non-blocking stream of information (in my particular case a MongoDB ChangeSteam; it could also be a Kafka consumer).

For the sake of reproducibility, in the example below I implement a generic asynchronous iterator `AsyncIteratorDummy`  that mimics the behaviour of a data stream:

```
import asyncio
from shiny import reactive, ui, Inputs, Outputs, Session, App, render

class AsyncIteratorDummy:
''' Iterate over an asynchronous source n Iterations.'''

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.current = 0
        self.n = n
    def __aiter__(self):
        return self
    async def __anext__(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"get next element {self.current}")
        self.current += 1
        if self.current > self.n:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        return self.current - 1

async def watch_changes(rval: reactive.Value):
    async for i in AsyncIteratorDummy(5):
        print(f"next element {i}")
        rval.set(i)
           

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    "This should update automatically",
    ui.output_text_verbatim("async_text"),
)

def server(input: Inputs, output: Outputs, session: Session):

    triggered_val = reactive.Value(-1)
    
    asyncio.create_task(watch_changes(triggered_val))
    
    @output(id="async_text")
    @render.text()
    async def _():
        return triggered_val.get()
    
    # un/commenting this makes makes the invalidation
    # of `triggered_val` effective or not:
    @reactive.Effect
    def _():
        reactive.invalidate_later(0.1)

app = App(app_ui, server)
```

The app *works* because of the presence of

```
    @reactive.Effect
    def _():
        reactive.invalidate_later(0.1)
```

Else, `async_text` greys out (indicating it has been invalidated) but does not update.

Is it possible to implement the asynchronous iteration without the "hack" of the `reactive.Effect` invalidating on loop?

My supposition is that I have to "flush" or "execute" invalidated variables in the context of `watch_changes()` (after `rval.set(i)`), using a low-level `py-shiny` function that I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `reactive.flush()`.

```py
async def watch_changes(rval: reactive.Value):
    async for i in AsyncIteratorDummy(5):
        print(f"next element {i}")
        rval.set(i)
        reactive.flush()
```

Comment: That was the key, thanks! I still had to await it, the last line is thus `await reactive.flush()`. I can also confirm this works with a MongoDB Change Stream